# Unable to run cleanmgr to clean Windows Update files

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

When I try to run `cleanmgr` it takes a long time to go over the phase of scanning for Windows Update files to be cleaned up. At that time the `cleanmgr` process and `TiWorker` process are eating whole CPU core each. Looks like it eventually gives up and shows the list with checkboxes, but without an option to select Windows Update files.

I tried to run:

- [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971058/en-us) fix
- the `sfc /scannow`
- `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`

But none helped.

There's nothing interesting in Event Viewer.

I'd like to know what's the problem. And how to solve it, if possible.

I'm running Win 8.1 Pro x64.

Comment: Did you really start it explicitly as Admin?

Comment: In W10 there's no UAC prompt when starting cleanmgr.exe as admin if account is admin,

Answer (score 2):

To output the results of sfc to something you can read, run the following in command prompt, might be some clues in there as to any sfc failures.

```
findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.tx
```

'

Also check the cleanmgr log for clues at:

```
C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\deepclean.log
```

EDIT:

It appears the deepclean log no longer exists in Windows 8, check the log below to see if there are any clues.

```
C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

You can also try starting cleanmgr as a run command, use the following string to run it.

```
cleanmgr.exe sageset:10
```

This command opens an extended Disk Cleanup with more options.

Do not clean up the "Windows ESD Installation Files"

Some people report this may run for hours before finishing, let it run uninterrupted.

Comment: The `deepclean.log` does not exist. In `CBS.log` there's no error related to `[SR]` (http://pastebin.com/Renijc46).

Comment: @cincura.net, Check my edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. There are no timestamps in the `dism.log` so it's hard to guess whether it's related. I uploaded it to http://ge.tt/1vS230H2/v/0 . There's few `There is not enough space on the disk.` and also probably some messed up encoding. I tried the `sageset` and `sagerun`, it did something (I checked everything ESD files included). Not sure it succeeded with WU files.

Comment: I would free up some disk space.

Comment: At that time there was 20+GB on a system drive. :\

Comment: Run a chkdsk on the hard drive, it may have free space issues which can cause crazyness with io operations on the disk.

Comment: I cleaned up ESD files yesterday. I was too fast clicking. :\ But these are not needed for system to run, AFAIK.

Comment: Well `chkdsk` found nothing (`Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.`).

Comment: I once mistakenly cancelled out of Disk Cleanup: "Clean System files", and then the [option never came up](https://superuser.com/questions/1042329/where-is-the-clean-up-system-files-in-disk-cleanup-wizard) on next run. On newer systems, the event log may reveal issues with WU: (a golden oldie was [0x80070057](https://superuser.com/questions/1330011/getting-0x80070057-in-windows-update-when-trying-to-update-to-build-17686)). Apart from the DISM log, there's very little for troubleshooting other than delete the SWD folder.

Answer (score 0):

cleanmgr.exe.mui missing in windows/system32/en-US (or xx-XX > your language).
can be found in Winsxs

Comment: This is a bit cryptic.  Can you expand your answer to clarify how to solve the problem?