# Where is the " Clean up System Files" in "Disk Cleanup Wizard"?

Tags: windows-7, disk-cleanup, winsxs

I am trying to reduce the size of my WinSxS folder by following this article on How-To Geek:

http://www.howtogeek.com/174705/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-your-winsxs-folder-on-windows-7-or-8/

In there it says:

> To clean up such update files, open the Disk Cleanup wizard (tap the
>   Windows key, type “disk cleanup” into the Start menu, and press
>   Enter). Click the Clean up System Files button, enable the Windows
>   Update Cleanup option and click OK. If you’ve been using your Windows
>   7 system for a few years, you’ll likely be able to free several
>   gigabytes of space.

Well, I have been using my Windows 7 (Ultimate, 32-bit, VMWare VM) for several years, running Windows Update regularly, but for some reason my Disk Cleaner wizard is not giving me the "Clean up System Files" button:

[image]

One may say, that this is because there is nothing to clean up but I have verified that my monstrous 5.7GB WinSxS folder indeed contains junk from prior years.

I also tried to use CCleaner but to no avail.

Any idea what I am missing?

**== UPDATE ==**

After @magicandre1981 kindly explaining how to find that button and that I was essentially already running as if the button were pressed (by virtue of running it as Administrator), I tried DISM:

```
DISM /online /cleanup-Image /spsuperseded
```

[image]

It appears that DISM does what Disk Cleanup does for system files. Is that so?

Comment: Disk Cleanup calls DISM to perform the Windows Update Cleanup. The command is Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn251565.aspx . The Windows 7 version of DISM has fewer options than later Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It already shows you all options to clean system files (system service pack cleanup and the dialog `more options` are a system task).

Running it as normal user doesn't show it and shwos the button:

[image]

This happens if you run `%windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe` always as admin or disabled the UAC completely, here `cleanmgr.exe` always runs as admin.

Comment: Indeed, I ran it as Administrator. Now when I run it as a standard user I can see the button and clicking it shows the same as the screenshot in my original posting. Accepting +1. Now I have to figure out how to reduce the size of that WinSxS folder because that article on How-To Geek is useless to me in light of the fact that Disk Cleanup wizard shows nothing to cleanup.

Comment: There is nothing to reduce.  WinSxS is the size it needs to be, if you want all recovery options available to you, any removal of a component will mean any system file corruption will result in recovery options being unavailable to you.

Comment: if you can't see the WindowsUpdate Cleanup option, you already removed all possible old updates (check the file **C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\DeepClean.log** for more details) There is a 3rd party tool called **Rebase** which claims to do more cleanup, but you have to pay for it: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/174816-windows-7-resetbase-backport/

Comment: @magicandre1981 There is no **C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\DeepClean.log** in my system (CBS subdirectory exists but it's empty). I might try `DISM.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase` (after careful consideration).

Comment: /ResetBase is not available in Win7, only in 8.1 (also not in Win10). I see the file on my Win7 Desktop PC after installing this update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2852386