# Getting 0x80070057 in Windows Update when trying to update to Build 17686

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-insider

Windows Update tries to install the update as usual, and then after a while, I get a download error 0x80070057:

[image: Build 17686 Error 0x80070057 Windows Update]

At first I thought this was a storage issue (I had 3 GB of free space at the time), so I moved some of my 'heavy stuff' like anime and software setups to my private LAN file server, and now I have 14.9 GB of free space.

Please help me solve this issue. I really want this build.

Comment: Some reading here....https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-windows-update-error-0x80070057/

Comment: generate your [own ISO from the UUP files](https://uup.rg-adguard.net/), mount the ISO, run setup.exe and keep apps + settings when doing the upgrade.

Comment: @magicandre1981 It's downloading a bunch of stuff. I only have 18 GB of disk space left, is this enough for it to do everything?

Comment: @magicandre1981 The upgrade failed

Comment: [use 2 USB drives to update](https://superuser.com/a/1324429/174557)

Comment: try the [Insider Preview Build 17704](https://superuser.com/a/1334775/174557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 17704](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/06/27/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17704/) via Windows Update. It includes a fix for error **0x80070057**

> **General changes, improvements, and fixes for PC**
>
> - We fixed an issue that could result in seeing a **0x80070057 error in Windows Update when upgrading** to the last few flights.

Comment: It's fine if I just generate the ISO from the UUP files right? Or will it not work?

Comment: if you generated the 17704 ISO it should now work. Try it

Comment: I got a lot of errors in the console. Mostly file not found errors, and my ISO file is 3.88 GB. Is this normal?

Comment: which errors? which cpu type (x86, x64) and which edition have you selected?

Comment: I selected x64.

Comment: When I try to install it, it's giving a lot of 'run out of disk space' errors. I'm going to try uninstalling a bunch of stuff before giving it another try.

Comment: [use the way with 2 USB drives](https://superuser.com/a/1324429/174557)

Comment: That screen doesn't even come for me. And I've installed it now, Microsoft Edge was using 40 GB to store my browsing data, so I cleared it. Now the only problem I have now is I can't use some of the UWP apps. It says the app needs to be registered first.

Comment: try this: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3175-reinstall-re-register-apps-windows-10-a.html

Comment: That's the exact website I tried before. Didn't work.